# Execute a specific vbs cript in NSIS with custom parameter / argument input configuration

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, nsis

I am trying to get coorrect sytax to call these two commands using `nsExec::ExecuteToStack`, but still got no successful execution. Proboably I have wrong input formatting.

1st command:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack `"$SYSDIR\CScript.exe" $0 //$SYSDIR\iisext.vbs //EnApp //"ASP.NET 4.0.30319"`
```

2nd command:

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 “true”
```

, which, imho, should be something similar to:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack /NOUNLOAD `"$SYSDIR\CScript.exe" $0 //C:\Inetpub\Adminscripts\adsutil.vbs //set "W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64" “true”`
```

Could you please help me making correct execution string for ExecuteToStack function?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I have found a correct sytax for this one :)

Link:

http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=290922

Thank you that I found it because I simply do not uderstand why it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doubling slashes?

In MS Shell, you might need to escape backslashes as `\/` but not slashes. So no, in Windows shell, `//` is **not** equivalent to `/`.

And beware of your `"true"` parameter that is misquoted `“true”` as the shell understands regular simple and double quotes and not the typographic quotes. I suppose it is a copy/paste problem.

Comment: No, sorry, corrected typo but still - no result :( Functions, though, seems to be called, but no result in IIS Manager [ OS: 2k3 R2 Ent x64 ] :(

Comment: @HX_unbanned: did you first tried the `cscript.exe` command directly from the command shell? Is it doing whet you expect in this case ? You must ensure first that what is the correct command before trying to adapt in NSIS.

Comment: Yes. both works like a charm form cmd :/ Maybe you have some small vbs to share having any of these tasks, so I could exec them as single vbs without worruing about additional params?